# Php 5.3 upgrade at Debian lenny

Tags: apache-2.2, php

How can I upgrade php to 5.3 version at Debian lenny from squeeze packages?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `apt-pinning'. Here's a good tutorial

http://jaqque.sbih.org/kplug/apt-pinning.html